# Excel Formula for Return column name

Tags: excel, excel-formula, array-formulas

To describe my set up, I have rows of different projects with columns labeled as dates.  Each column has a date range and the row contains a number of hours.

To provide background, I am trying to determine what date a certain project ends based on if there are hours in the column (date range).

Here is the formula currently being used. However, I am not really following why I am subtracting 20. I am thinking there has to be a clearer way.

```
=IF(Q22=0,"",INDEX($U$2:$DY$5,2,MAX(IF($U22:$DY22>0,COLUMN($U22:$DY22)))-20))
```

What I am doing is checking if the total hours = 0 before trying to check when the date ends.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please note, that this is not a free code-writing service, but we are eager to help fellow programmers (and aspirants) writing their own code. Please read the help topics on [How To Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To"). Afterwards, please update your question with the `VBA` code you have written thus far in order to complete the task(s) you wish to achieve. Even recording a macro is a way to start.

Comment: Apart from the above, what do you actually want / need? Does the formula you have work? I presume as you're asking why you're subtracting 20 you didn't write it.

Comment: Column U is column number 21, so -20 from the result will give you 1,2,3,4 as you drag the formula across the columns.  So the INDEX formula looks at the range U2:DY5 in row 2 - it might as well just look at U3:DY3 row 1.   The `MAX(IF...` part looks at row 22 to find the maximum value that is greater than 0 and returns that column number, it then removes 20 to give 1,2,3,4 etc which is used as the column number in the INDEX formula. (hope that's understandable).

Comment: Well... if each row have an unique ID, you better use vlookup.

Comment: @SkipIntro. Yes, the formula works, but as you could tell I didn't write it and the person who did is no longer around to really explain it. Therefore, in order to enhance what I am doing, I will need to understand how this formula works or how to improve it.

Comment: @anakpanti I assumed index+match is better than vlookup?

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Thank you! That definitely makes sense.